# Red Browser App & mobile device tracking

Tags: mobile

What specific information about your mobile device is shared with a web host see when accessing it through the red browser app?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use [xhaus.com/headers](http://xhaus.com/headers) to see what headers your browser sends.
2. You can spoof your user-agent under 'Browser Settings'

Answer (score 1):

It is not browser-specific by the way, the details about your device can be gathered via JavaScript and posted via xmlHttpRequest query as HTTP headers, by the way : see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661157/how-to-add-header-data-in-xmlhttprequest-when-using-formdata). You need to use tcpdump or WireShark to check al the traffic, because xmlHttpRequest can ignore/avoid proxy settings...